# Encountering a " does not contain a definition for " error with a script. What may be causing this in my code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was able to troubleshoot the issues up until a certain point when I came across this error in unity:

Assets\code\StalkerAI.cs(164,45): error CS0117: 'NavMeshAgent' does not contain a definition for 'setDestination'

I know for certain that this should have worked for this function, but I am unsure why it is not. I would like to know what exactly I am getting wrong here.

Here is the issue code that they are seeing (I would be more specific if I knew which "NavMeshAgent.setDestination" they are speaking of, but here we are):

```
    m_WaitTime = startWaitTime;
    m_TimeToRotate = timeToRotate;

    m_CurrentWaypointIndex = 0;
    NavMeshAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();

    NavMeshAgent.isStopped = false;
    NavMeshAgent.speed = speedWalk;
    NavMeshAgent.SetDestination(waypoints[m_CurrentWaypointIndex].position);

}
void Update()
{
    EnviromentView();
    if (!m_IsPatrol)
    {
        Chasing();
    }
    else
    {
        Patroling();
    }
   
}
private void Chasing()
{
    m_PlayerNear = false;
    playerLastPosition = Vector3.zero;

    if (!m_CaughtPlayer)
    {
        Move(speedRun);
        NavMeshAgent.SetDestination(m_PlayerPosition);
    }
    if(NavMeshAgent.remainingDistance <= NavMeshAgent.stoppingDistance){
        if(m_WaitTime <= 0 && !m_CaughtPlayer && Vector3.Distance(transform.position, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("player").transform.position)>= 6f)
        {
            m_IsPatrol = true;
            m_PlayerNear = false;
            Move(speedWalk);
            m_TimeToRotate = timeToRotate;
            m_WaitTime = startWaitTime;
            NavMeshAgent.SetDestination(waypoints[m_CurrentWaypointIndex].position);
        }
        else
        {
            if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("player").transform.position)>= 2.5f)
            {
                Stop();
                m_WaitTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
    }
}
private void Patroling()
{
    if (m_PlayerNear)
    {
        if(m_TimeToRotate <= 0)
        {
            Move(speedWalk);
            LookingPlayer(playerLastPosition);
        }
        else
        {
            Stop();
            m_TimeToRotate -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        m_PlayerNear = false;
        playerLastPosition = Vector3.zero;
        NavMeshAgent.SetDestination(waypoints[m_CurrentWaypointIndex].position);
        if(NavMeshAgent.remainingDistance <= NavMeshAgent.stoppingDistance)
        {
            if(m_WaitTime <=0)
            {
                NextPoint();
                Move(speedWalk);
                m_WaitTime = startWaitTime;
            }
            else
            {
                Stop();
                m_WaitTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
    }
}
void Move(float speed)
{
    NavMeshAgent.isStopped = false;
    NavMeshAgent.speed = speed;
}
void Stop()
{
    NavMeshAgent.isStopped = true;
    NavMeshAgent.speed = 0;
}
public void NextPoint()
{
    m_CurrentWaypointIndex = (m_CurrentWaypointIndex + 1) % waypoints.Length;
    NavMeshAgent.SetDestination(waypoints[m_CurrentWaypointIndex].position);
}

void CaughtPlayer()
{
    m_CaughtPlayer = true;
}
void LookingPlayer(Vector3 player)
{
    NavMeshAgent.SetDestination(player);
    if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player)<= 0.3)
    {
        if(m_WaitTime <= 0)
        {
            m_PlayerNear = false;
            Move(speedWalk);
            UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent.setDestination(waypoints[m_CurrentWaypointIndex].position);
```

If you want the full script, let me know.

Comment: It's **S**etDestination: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent.SetDestination.html

Comment: The comment above is giving you the answer, but in the future: the error gives you a line number. Next time please give us *that line* and then some context. We don't get line numbers here.

Comment: Just so you have more context, Unity does not give me a specific line number, it never does for me. It always gives a range like 160-70 or whatever as an example. I also don't get any indication of error in Microsoft visual studio either, so I have no idea what specific line of code is the issue. It especially doesn't help that I am inexperienced in C# and the teacher I am doing this for has no knowledge of coding. If you have any suggestions for improving error detection either in unity, visual studio or via some external software or tools, let me know.

Comment: `Assets\code\StalkerAI.cs(164,45): error CS0117: ` -> source line 164, character position 45, in file "StalkerAI.cs". Your editor should show you which line that is.

Comment: ok, I think I may have just been misreading Unity errors. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Double clicking the error takes you to the line usually too

Comment: `Unity does not give me a specific line number, it never does for me. It always gives a range like 160-70 or whatever as an example.` -> that's not a range ^^ the first number is the line index the second number is the character index ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you named your variable exactly like the class NavMeshAgent. I would recommend to slightly change the variable name - maybe this is causing some issues.

You could also try using the property `NavMeshAgent.destination = (Vector3) newDestination`.

Comment: It's a typo in the code, as mentioned in [the comment posted ten minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74594691/encountering-a-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-error-with-a-script-what-m#comment131670735_74594691).

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but how/where would I use that property in my code? if you could point out at least where it would go that would be great.

Comment: Your error: `UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent.setDestination(waypoints[m_CurrentWaypointIndex].position);`

Comment: I highly recommend checking out some tutorials on how to debug and read error codes or you're going to have a really, really long time.

Comment: @Chuck to be fair it is a combination of both things ;) Yes there is the typo with `setDestination` -> `SetDestination` ... but [`NavMeshAgent.SetDestination`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent.SetDestination.html) is also **not static** so OP doesn't want to call it on `UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent` but rather on OP's class field called `NavMeshAgent`